# Hide the unchecked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the unchecked radio buttons hide, and just display the checked one:

```
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">
<li >
    <input type="radio" id="woof_72_55cb07a61800a" class="woof_radio_term" data-slug="elektronik" name="product_cat" value="72">
    <label for="woof_72_55cb07a61800a">Elektronik <span>(812)</span></label>
</li>
<li >
    <input type="radio" id="woof_113_55cb07a741fec" class="woof_radio_term" data-slug="pompa-air" name="product_cat" value="113" checked="checked">
    <label for="woof_113_55cb07a741fec" checked="checked" style="font-weight: bold;">Pompa Air <span>(29)</span></label>
</li>
<li >
    <input type="radio" id="woof_184_55cb07a7513ac" class="woof_radio_term" data-slug="brand" name="product_cat" value="184">
    <label for="woof_184_55cb07a7513ac">Brand <span>(814)</span></label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul.woof_list").find("li").each(function(index){

        $(this).find('input[checked="checked"]', ".woof_list");

        $( this ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        // by default, hide all li's
        $( 'ul.woof_list li' ).toggle();
        $( '.woof_is_closed' ).trigger('click');
            // show only the selected li
        $( this ).show();
     });
    console.log($(this).find('input[checked="checked"]', ".woof_list").val());
```

I got the value of the radio button, but I do not know what should I do then.

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').hide()` ?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. When you click one of the radiobuttons, you want to hide the 2 others that are not checked, or?

Comment: Ya not clear because you are setting your logic inside pseudo ready event so if you want it by default, just use CSS ↯↯↯

Comment: `input[type=radio]:not(:checked) { display: none; }`

Comment: you mean you want to hide the label of the radio button which is unchecked ?

Comment: So after the user clicks a selection, they cannot change it? Sounds like a very confusing and frustrating user interface.  Don't do it.

Comment: @Loyalar yes i want hide the other (not checked)

Comment: @JimGarrison you are right, maybe i will put the reset button for this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').on('change', function () {
        $(':radio').not($(this)).closest('li').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ds3Lfms7/1/

It will hide all the other li's when you check one

Comment: Thanks this is solving the question !

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you want to keep the toggle behavior you had, so clicking the radio again will bring up all options you may want to try that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.woof_list li input[type='radio']").click( function( e ) {

        // hide all li's (or show all)
        $( 'ul.woof_list li' ).toggle();

        // show only the selected li
        $(this).parent().show();

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/optionsit/pa0Lmwpg/2/

Comment: While the other answers are also correct, please allow the user to re-select if he makes a mistake, as this code allows. This is just better UX.

Comment: Yeah but it will probably need some tweak at the implementation. i left `$( '.woof_is_closed' ).trigger('click');` because it was part of the question, but that will get triggered when the user want to re-select. edit: I just deleted that line, just keep in mind that every instruction on the click function will get executed on "re-select"

Answer (score 1):

If you asking for hiding only unchecked radio button then Try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvkm6ypf/)

```
 $('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').hide();

    $('li').click( function () {
        $('input[type=radio]').show();
        $('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [@DGS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31960760/2066079) and [@Lorenzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961356/2066079). It uses DGS's cleaner form, but has Lorenzo's toggle() feature to allow the user to re-show the items by clicking re-clicking. This is just better UX, allowing the user to correct his choice in case the he made a mistake, initially.

[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/n0xxk6m7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').on('click', function () {
        $(':radio').not($(this)).closest('li').toggle();
    });
});
```

Where's Lorenzo's answer does not work properly with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 checked, this answer does.